# # Aidl not found, please install it

Tags: apt, android

I am trying to run `buildozer`. While running it gave the following error:

```
Aidl not found, please install it.
```

So I tried to install aidl as described [here](http://thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/aidl)
But it gave me the following error

> E: Unable to locate package aidl

I have updated the package index by `sudo apt-get update`,but stil it is not working. How can I install aidl?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? you may need to [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) first

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04. I tried `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, it said `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Comment: Also, I am running ubuntu bash on windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution. To install `aidl`, you need `libstdc++-6`. Previously I had a lower version of `libstdc++`, which causes problems while installing `aidl`.

To update to `libstdc++-6`, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

After this, you will have `libstdc++6` installed.now you can simply install the `aidl` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install aidl
```

Comment: This should be a reported as a bug, because aidl should mark in it's *.deb file all it's dependancies

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's very specific versions of Cython required so make sure you use the appropriate [Ubuntu dependencies installation from this site](http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

For Ubuntu 16.04 it is:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cython==0.21
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential ccache git libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 python2.7 python2.7-dev openjdk-8-jdk unzip zlib1g-dev zlib1g:i386
```

Then if you still get an issue, try running the android SDK Manager GUI and manually installing the dependencies:

```
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android
```

Replace android-sdk-20 with your version

[image]

Then I had to delete the OLD version first, and then reinstall a later version of the SDK and rerun it

### For Windows WSL Ubuntu

If running withing Windows Ubuntu WSL you can still do this, just:

On Windows Run XLaunch (from [Xming X Server for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/))

Then in WSL Ubuntu prompt (I use hyper.js):

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

### Last resort

If you still can't get buildozer to run, you can try [the kivy VM at the bottom of this download page](https://kivy.org/#download) (requires Virtual Box and possibly a BIOS change to enable virtualization)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to compile for SDK 28, didn't have `build-tools` folder at all, so I had to run this:

```
~/./.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.0"
```

That command installed build tools with aidl inside `build-tools` folder and fixed the issue.