# Cannot install aidl

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am trying to get buildozer working (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468917/how-to-fix-buildozer-build-fails-with-cmake-error)).

when I follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930460/aidl-not-found-please-install-it) to install aidl, I get the following error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aidl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for aidl
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Where can we get "buildozer" sources?

Comment: @N0rbert. Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I have tried to just run the buildozer from the command line and using Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us follow guide from [pypi `buildozer` page](https://pypi.org/project/buildozer/).

We can use one of the options below - binary or source install.

## Binary install

We need:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install buildozer paramiko # the latter is to fix warning about missied paramiko
```

Then check that it is working:

> ```
> $ buildozer --version
> Buildozer 0.39
> ```

---

## Source install

We need:

```
cd ~/Downloads 
sudo apt-get install git python-pip
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer
cd buildozer
python setup.py build
sudo pip install -e .
```

Then check that it is working:

> ```
> $ buildozer --version  
> Buildozer 0.40.dev0
> ```

---

[AIDL is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=aidl) in all Ubuntu releases. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install aidl
```

Comment: Thank you. Buildozer is installed and buildozer --version gives Buildozer 0.39. The problem seems to be aidl when I try ro run buildozer

Comment: AIDL is packaged in all Ubuntu releases. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install aidl`.